# How to detect double-byte characters in Apex?

Tags: apex, string

I have a requirement to detect double-byte characters in Apex, characters like "你好我是一个数位开发平台" instead of alpha characters that appear in English, French, German, etc. What's a good way to do achieve this detection in Apex?

```
@isTest
private class StringUtilTest() {

    @isTest
    private static void detectDoublebyte() {

        // Double-byte characters
        System.assertEquals(true, StringUtil.detectDoublebyte('I am a 平台'),
                'Double-byte characters should have been detected');

        // No double-byte characters
        System.assertEquals(false, StringUtil.detectDoublebyte('I am a platform'),
                'No double-byte characters should have been detected');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions to the rescue! I just searched for this one and found [this blog post](https://mf9it.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/detect-double-byte-characters-in-utf-8-string/), converted it to Apex, and it works! For your input/output combos anyway. You may wish to do more extensive testing.

**Execute Anonymous Script**

```
Boolean containsDoubleByteCharacters(String input)
{
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile('[\\u0000-\\u007F]*').matcher(input);
    return !m.matches();
}

// Double-byte characters
System.assertEquals(true, containsDoubleByteCharacters('I am a 平台'),
                    'Double-byte characters should have been detected');

// No double-byte characters
System.assertEquals(false, containsDoubleByteCharacters('I am a platform'),
                    'No double-byte characters should have been detected');
```